# ES6 Class gives error when I instantiate it

Tags: ecmascript-6, jspm

I am getting up to speed on ES6 classes loaded with JSPM.

For example:

```
export class Alerter{
    doAlert(message)
    {
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

Then I import this above another class:

```
import Alerter from 'services/alerter';
```

Then I use the class:

```
var alerter = new Alerter();
```

This line throws an error:  `object does not support his method.`

Is there a different way I should be writing this?

Comment: I'm curious, what browser are you using? I'm pretty sure my answer below is the issue, but that error message isn't one I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exporting a named export and importing the default export. You either need to do

```
export default class Alerter {
```

so that you have an export to import, or

```
import {Alerter} from 'services/alerter';
```

so that you import the correct constructor.

Comment: Thank you, both of those work.  (The browser I am testing with is IE 11. In Chrome, the error was "undefined is not a function")